# how to auto trigger onChange function with selected value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a dropdown which i would like to trigger a function when something is selected.

```
<DatePicker
  customInput={
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex}
        className="exact-date-input"
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        autoComplete="off"
        type="text"
        maxLength={10}
        id="date-input"
        aria-label={ariaLabel}
        value={this.state.inputValue}
        onKeyDown={this.onKeyDownDateType}
        onClick={()=>this.openOrCloseDatePicker(true, this.state.error)}
        onFocus={()=>this.openOrCloseDatePicker(true, this.state.error)}
        onBlur={()=>this.emptyIfError(this.state.error)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  }
  openToDate={this.openToDate(this.props.value)}
  tabIndex={-1}
  selected={this.openToDate(this.props.value)}
  customInputRef="dateInput"
  autoComplete="off"
  id={this.props.id}
  onChange={this.handleInput}
  required={this.props.required}
  minDate={moment(today).toDate()}
  maxDate={moment(endRange).toDate()}
  open={this.state.datePickerIsOpen}
  onClickOutside={()=>this.openOrCloseDatePicker(false, this.state.error)}
/>
```

Here is my onChange function

```
  handleInput(e:any) {
    let value = moment(e).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

    this.props.onChange({
      target: {
        name: this.props.name,
        value: value
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      inputValue: value,
      datePickerIsOpen: false
    })

  }
```

The problem I have is that the function is not triggered if i choose option that has already been selected. I do understand that this is because nothing has been changed but is there a way around this?

Comment: Anyone have idea how to fix this issues?

Answer (score 1):

> I do understand that this is because nothing has been changed.

Clearly `onChange` is only invoked if something changes.

## Fix

Look at the API of the `DatePicker` that you are using and see if it has a prop like `onSelect`, or `onOpen` something to that effect and use that

Comment: So I just need to add `onSelect={this.handleInput}` in DatePicker? im using react-datepicker